# Applescript for creating New Message with Mail application

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript for Mail.app which opens a new message window with pre-defined recipient address and subject. This script opens a new window every time I run it:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"some subject", content:"" & return & return}
    tell newMessage
        set visible to true
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"some name", address:"some address"}
    end tell
    activate
end tell
```

But I want the script to open a new message window only when the previously opened window is closed – otherwise, the previously opened window should come to the front.

Can anyone please help me in modifying this script to achieve the above mentioned functionality?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test this but it should do what you need... at least it shows you the proper approach. You basically use a "property" to keep track of some value from the last time the script was run. In this case we check for the name of the frontmost window and see if it matches your criteria. If the window name doesn't do what you need then just find some other value to track between launches of the script. The basic approach should work.

EDIT: using the ID of the message, which is unique, the following will do what you want:

```
property lastWindowID : missing value
tell application "Mail"
    set windowIDs to id of windows
    if windowIDs does not contain lastWindowID then
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"some subject", content:"" & return & return}
        tell newMessage
            set visible to true
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"some name", address:"some address"}
        end tell
        activate
        set lastWindowID to id of window 1
    else
        tell window id lastWindowID
            set visible to false
            set visible to true
        end tell
        activate
    end if
end tell
```

the visibility toggle seems to be the only way to get the window in front, as `frontmost` is a read-only property. The *lastWindowID* property will store the ID as long as the script is not re-compiled (*caveat empteor*: do not put this into an Automator service, as these get re-compiled every time the service is loaded).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.This works fine only if other mail windows are not opened.If other windows are opened then the value returned for name of window 1 will be wrong one.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if the window name doesn't do it then use some other attribute. A window has many attributes so you need to find something unique.

Comment: @regulus6633: actually, `window 1` will always return the message window, as that is the active window on creation – your original script created duplicate new messages not because of that, but because of of the second condition it tested for (`window 1 is lastWindowName` results in a new message being created when the window is open). I edited that, switched to testing for the window id (unique, unlike the window name) and added an `else` clause to bring the open window to the front.